# How to prevent two succeeding spaces in an Antlr rule?

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

As a lexer rule I'd like to match a string according to these rules:

- must not contain tabs (\t) or line breaks (\r, \n)
- must not contain two succeeding spaces
- can contain all other characters, including single spaces

I came up with:

```
STRING: ~[\t\r\n]*
```

But I don't know how to prevent succeeding spaces.

Comment: Does your string have no delimiters like `"`?

Comment: The string's possible delimiters are \t, \n (and/or \r) and two succeeding spaces. Please don't ask why :P

Comment: Both in front and at the end of the string? Maybe include some sample (in)valid strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
STRING: 
     (
        ~[\t\r\n ] // non-whitespace
     | ' ' ~[\t\r\n ] // or single space followed by non-whitespace
     )+
     ' '?  // may optionally end in a space (if desired, remote the line otherwise)
     ;
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I then modified your proposal and ended up with `STRING: ~[ \t\r\n]+ (' ' ~[ \t\r\n]+)* ;` in order to prevent leading and trailing space (which I did not know to be relevant when I asked the question).